# Unable to create a new angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am new to Angular and I am facing the following problem in creating a new project. I have already installed nodejs and npm which are the prerequisites of Angular. I also installed the angular CLI but when I am trying to create a new project the following error is coming.

[⠼ Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, [see](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please [see](https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated)
npm WARN deprecated [resolve-url@0.2.1](https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated)
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...p":"^0.8.0","grunt-co'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/saumya/.npm/_logs/2020-04-12T15_22_00_125Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. [See above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjwaQ.png)

Comment: You can ignore all the warnings. They only mean that a package is outdated. The only interesting thing is the error. Could you post the package.json and log file?

Comment: you need to clear npm cache. If u are using windows location is C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache. Simply delete cache folder and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear npm cache. If u are using windows location is C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache. Simply delete cache folder and try again

If this also not work, it's better to install the latest npm and angular by removing the old version and npm-cache as well. Then you will have the latest compatible versions

Answer (score 1):

remove this folder: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache.

OR

Run this command:
npm cache clear --force